# Convert an UPDATE into a SELECT

Tags: sql, regex

I'm making a simple web interface to allow execution of queries against a database (yeah, I know, I know it's a really bad practice, but it's a private website used only by a few trusted users that currently use directly a DB manager to execute these queries, so the web interface is only to make more automatic the process).

The thing is that, for safety, whenever an UPDATE query is detected I want to first execute a SELECT statement "equivalent" to the update (keeping WHERE clause) to retrieve how many records are going to be affected prior to execute the UPDATE.

The idea is to replace "UPDATE" by "SELECT * FROM" and remove the whole "SET" clause without removing the "WHERE".
I'm trying replacing `UPDATE\s*(.*?)\s*SET.*(\s*WHERE\s*.*)` by `SELECT * FROM \1 \2` and similar but i'm having troubles when there is no "WHERE" clause (uncommon, but possible).

**edit:** It's pretty hard to explain why I need this to be done like this, but I do, I know about stored procedures, query builders, transactions, etc... but for my case it's not what I need to be able to do.

Comment: You need the complete SQL syntax for this (consider string values containing WHERE, SET etc...)

Comment: You could instead begin a transaction, execute the update (and capture the metadata) then perform a rollback.

Answer (score 2):

You should fix your design.  There is nothing wrong with users updating data in a database.  The question is *how* they do it.  My strong suggestion is to wrap the `update` statements in *stored procedures*.  Then only allow updates through the stored procedures.

There are several main reasons why I prefer this approach:

- I think a well-designed API produces more stable and maintainable code.
- The stored procedures control security.
- The stored procedures allow better logging of what is happening in the database.
- The stored procedures provide control over what users can do.

In your case, though, they offer another advantage.  Because all the `update` code is on the database-side, you know what the update statements look like.  So, you can then decide how you want to get the "pre-counts" (which is what I assume you are looking for).

EDIT:

There is also an important flaw in your design (as you describe it).  The data might change between the `update` and the `select`.  If you use stored procedures, there are ways to address this.  For instance, you can wrap the operations in a transaction.  Or, you use a `SELECT` to get the rows to be updated, lock those rows (depending on the database), and only do the update on those rows.

Comment: Actually for my use case this is not a solution because this is just for some few "weird" and mixed scenarios and the same update query is probably never executed again